# Spectrum of a symmetric saddle point matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, eigenvalues, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let $C=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   A & B^{T} \\
   B & O \\
  \end{array} } \right]$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is SPD, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $m\leq n$. The matrix $B$ has full rank. Let $S=BA^{-1}B^{T}$ be the Schur complement of the matrix $C$. In 2015, Owe Axelsson proved that if $\lambda_{\min}(S)\leq\lambda_{\min}(A)$, then the bounds on the negative eigenvalues of $C$ are determined mainly by $S$. Are there any results which state the conditions on $A$ and $S$, which imply that $\lambda_{\min}(S)\leq\lambda_{\min}(A)$?

I have been trying to find a sharp lower bound for $\lambda_{\min}(C)$, when $C$ arises from a spectral discretization of the Stokes problem. I have sharp estimates for the spectrum of $A$ and the singular values of $B$.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the inequality about the minimal eigenvalues of S and A holds but with the reverse sign. Check a book by Vassilevski Multilevel block factorization, chapter 3. Upd: Never mind, in this book the setup is different. Still it may worth having a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. The book is helpful. I was able to prove the desired result by comparing the spectrum of S and A. I haven't seen anyone applying these results so I was curious about it.